# lvm and df inconsistent on amount of free space due to swap partition in middle?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, fedora

I recently did a fresh install of Fedora19 over Fedora17 on a system that is dual booted with Win7. Everything is working properly but what really confuses me is that lvm and df are inconsistent with showing the amount of free space there is on the extended partition. lvm reports 18.90GB free while df reports 31GB. When I view `system-config-lvm`, the swap partition is somehow in the middle of the volume group? Is the swap partition causing the inconsistency? If so, would it be a good idea to delete the swap partition and use a swap file instead?

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   37G  4.1G   31G  12% /  
devtmpfs                 1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev  
tmpfs                    1.5G 1012K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm  
tmpfs                    1.5G  1.0M  1.5G   1% /run  
tmpfs                    1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
tmpfs                    1.5G   28K  1.5G   1% /tmp  
/dev/sda3                477M  101M  348M  23% /boot  
/dev/sda2                239G  198G   41G  83% /mnt/sda2
```

`vgdisplay` output:

```
--- Volume group ---  
VG Name               fedora  
System ID               
Format                lvm2  
Metadata Areas        1  
Metadata Sequence No  4  
VG Access             read/write  
VG Status             resizable  
MAX LV                0  
Cur LV                2  
Open LV               2  
Max PV                0  
Cur PV                1  
Act PV                1  
VG Size               57.54 GiB  
PE Size               4.00 MiB  
Total PE              14730  
Alloc PE / Size       9891 / 38.64 GiB  
Free  PE / Size       4839 / 18.90 GiB   
VG UUID               fwfMnt-VXQi-c0DV-L3Oj-iv5N-hAaq-FhW6nu
```